# Issue with finding closest colors with taken image from camera

Tags: c#, opencv, colors

I have a project which needs to identify the closest color and corresponding location of the taken image from a Camera. However, right now I am facing the problem what the color cannot be correctly identified, could anyone can point me out what is my problems? Below is the flow of my project.

1. Taken an image from Camera as a template (Template). Template image contains various of objects which each object contains a dominant color and each objects are separated
2. Split the image based on no. of objects detected,in each object image, finding max. Location of H, S , V channels using 1D histogram.
3. Take another image (Target) using the same Camera, target image is similar to template image but the objects inside may a bit overlapped and/or locations are different
4. Using the information got in 2), finding the closest color using 3D distance and rebuild the image (ie. replacing each pixel value to the closest color). 
   If the pixels H value is 15deg away from the dominant H value got in 2), then the pixel will not be compared to that color.
5. Finding the contours of each color in rebuild target image, finding each color location.

Right now the problem is, when I rebuild the image in step 4, I found that the color is not identified correctly. some of the colors inside rebuilt image can be identified only in a very small portion, or with black pixels like pepper noise (since if none of the colors can be identified, ie. HUE value is +/-15deg away color to be compared, or S / V value is away from color to be compared, that pixel will be replaced to black pixel)

Even though if I take 2 images with object, location and light source the same, one image as the template and the other one is the target image, I found that the rebuild image color still contains error.

So now I am not sure what is the actual problem is, but my guess is coming from finding the H,S,V dominant location. Could it be better if I finding max. Location [H,S] and V channels instead of H,S,V channels separately? Or any suggestions to point out? Thanks a lot

[image: This is the image I take and rebuild, the first row is bad result and 2nd row is good result(The rebuilt image on right can be regenerated more than 80% of original area)]

Comment: can you show an example image that fails?

Comment: Edited with sample image added

Comment: are you taking in account the ranges of HSV in OpenCV? can you show a some code snippets?

Comment: Yes, that is in range of HSV (HSV_FULL) format and H values already handled 360 deg range. The codes are too long (cause my bad coding technique), but general idea as below:

Comment: 1. USE 1D Historgram to find domainant H,S,V values for each color, using mask the mask off unwanted region. 2. Generate a new image to full black color. 3. Compare the pixel 1 by 1 in the soucres image, finding the shortest color distance among colors got in step 1). 4. Replace black pixel to the color value with shortest distance. Remark. If either on the the cases occurs, color will not be compared in step 3 : a. H value of the color is more than +/-21 (ie. approx. +/-15deg in HUE wheel, or more than 50 in S,V value)